# Is there a way to make pandas sort_values default to descending?

Tags: python, pandas

The default behavior of sorting in pandas is ascending:

`DataFrame.sort_values(self, by, axis=0, ascending=True, inplace=False, kind='quicksort', na_position='last', ignore_index=False)`

Is there a way to change this default behavior (by using global option or something similar)?

Comment: Even if you could, it'd be a bad idea - it'd break all sorts of code you aren't even aware of that relies on the default being ascending.

Comment: Why? This sounds like a bad idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really need this, use `partialmethod` in the python standard library:

```
from functools import partialmethod

pd.DataFrame.sort_values = partialmethod(pd.DataFrame.sort_values, ascending=False)

df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(10).reshape(5, 2), columns=list('AB'))

   A  B
0  0  1
1  2  3
2  4  5
3  6  7
4  8  9

df.sort_values('A')

   A  B
4  8  9
3  6  7
2  4  5
1  2  3
0  0  1
```

Be CAREFUL with overwriting the method. Maybe don't overwrite if you can, and give it a different name it something descriptive or misleading like `shuffle` :):).

Comment: Thanks. Good answer! Should name it sort_values_descending

Answer (score 0):

You could use pd.DataFrame as a base class and override sort_values:

```
import pandas as pd

class CustDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    def sort_values(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs["ascending"] = False
        super().sort_values(*args, **kwargs)
```

seems to work as expected using the sort_values example from pandas documentation. As mentioned in the comments this could break various other methods.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, changing defaults in pandas `DataFrame.sort_values` is possible.

In pandas 1.3 or newer:

```
_pd.DataFrame.sort_values.__wrapped__.__defaults__ = tuple(
    False if i == 1 else value
    for i, value in enumerate(_pd.DataFrame.sort_values.__wrapped__.__defaults__)
)
```

In older versions of pandas just remove `__wrapped__` as it was not needed earlier.

The above line changes the second default argument (the first one is `axis=0`, the second one is `ascending=True`) to `False`. As mentioned in comments and other answers this is usually a bad idea, but there is a utility in changing the default sort order instead: you can change it to `stable` or `mergesort` to reduce the diffs in version control if you are committing outputs:

```
_pd.DataFrame.sort_values.__wrapped__.__defaults__ = tuple(
    'stable' if default == 'quicksort' else default
    for default in _pd.DataFrame.sort_values.__wrapped__.__defaults__
)
```